# Renaming a .obb file to .zip then unzipping and rezipping with 7-zip produces a file of different size

Tags: android, compression, zip, 7-zip

I transferred a .obb file from my Android phone to my Windows PC, renamed the file extension to .zip and unzipped it with 7-zip. This produced a folder with image, audio, and other files. When I rezipped it and transferred it back as a .obb the app did not work. According to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929273/how-to-create-obb-file-as-main-apk-expansion-file-using-jobb-tool) on this site .obb files should be zipped with the "Store" compression method, but this produced a .zip file that's about 36,000 KB larger than the original .obb file. I also tried the Android tool JOBB, but this produced an even bigger .obb file (~100,000 KB bigger). Why does unzipping and rezipping not produce a file of the same size as the original and how can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you run `unzip - l` against the original file and then on the new file you have created. If you update the question with that information it will pinpoint where they are different

Comment: @pmqs Thanks for the suggestion, but I am doing this with the GUI. I've never used the command line for 7-Zip before. Do you know what folder I need to add to the path to use that command?

Comment: Just post screenshots from the GUI. Important that you show the compressed & uncompressed sizes and the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZIP has different compression levels (in 7-Zip there are 5 different levels available plus no compression) and additional different compression algorithms (Deflate, ...).
Depending on which level was original selected and what level you selected the compressed size may vary.

Therefore it is nothing unusual that the compressed file size is different. The only relevant fact is the number of files, the decompressed size and of course the file and folder structure inside the ZIP file.

Comment: Turns out the .obb file contains a mix of Store and Deflate compressed files, which is probably why I couldn't get the file sizes to match when doing all store or all deflate.

Answer (score 0):

[.obb files are not limited](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files#Filename) to a specific input file type, but instead can be anything and will get renamed to `.obb` from the original extension.

If you want to figure out the exact compression level used you'll need to figure out how to read the format in a hex editor. Alternatively you could try the Python program mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535036/7665043), [hachoir](https://github.com/vstinner/hachoir). Although it is not maintained that's a recent change, and it's built for python3.6+.